# combining lines of DNA

Tags: python

I'll start by saying that I am very much a Python NEWBIE! I'm working on an assignment for my class, and we are to the part where we're on our own and are expected to do a few things that were weren't taught. That said:

I'm trying to combine multiple lines into a single line. I need this:

```
>taxon1
ACCGTGGATC
CCTATTGATT
GGATATTATC
```

To look like this:
taxon1 ACCGTGGATCCCTATTGATTGGATATTATC

I'm writing a python script and starting with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "usage: finalmyscript.py infile.txt"
    sys.exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]

handle = open(fname, "r")

for line in handle:
    handle.close()
```

Comment: Instead of reinvnenting the wheel concerning command line arguments, you should use the argparse module.

Comment: Or `tr '\n', '' file`.

Comment: Using tr would replace all newlines with the empty string which would not leave the space between the identifier line and the sequence

Answer (score 0):

For this example you are probably dealing with just a single sequence so this solution will work for what you are looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "usage: finalmyscript.py infile.txt"
    sys.exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]
handle = open( fname )

for line in handle:
  # Only the lines that are identifier lines(Aka, start with >)
  if line[0] == '>':
    # We could use print, but sys.stdout.write is just as easy to
    #  write to the terminal without a newline at the end
    sys.stdout.write( line.replace( '\n', ' ' ) )
  else:
    sys.stdout.write( line.replace( '\n', '' ) )

handle.close()
```

I leave it to you to figure out how to modify the code above to handle multiple sequences in a single file.

If you are going to be doing more Bioinformatics processing later on you should check out the [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) project which will make things much easier.

Here is an example to solve the above very easily using Biopython's SeqIO module

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "usage: finalmyscript.py infile.txt"
    sys.exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]

for seq in SeqIO.parse( fname, 'fasta' ):
    print ">" + seq.id + " " + str(seq.seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "usage: %s <input file>" % os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[1]
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    print(''.join([input_file.next().rstrip()[1:]+' '] +
                  [line.rstrip() for line in input_file]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
print "usage: finalmyscript.py infile.txt"
sys.exit(1)

fname = sys.argv[1]                                                
handle = open(fname, "r")
list = handle.readlines()

for line in list:
parts = line.rstrip().split('\n')
print "".join(parts)
```

Which gets rid of the newline characters, but it still won't bring everything onto one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    result=""
    for line in fname.readlines():
        if line[0]!=">": #does not import the first line with name of sequence
            result+=line.strip()
    fname.close()

    print result
```